# Unable to capture/redirect warning from Exchange cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am using trying to use the `Set-DistributionGroup` Exchange cmdlet in the following manner:

```
$Exch_Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $ExchangeURI -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $Exch_Session -commandname Set-DistributionGroup -AllowClobber

if (<condition>) {
    try {
        Set-DistributionGroup @Setparams
    }
    catch {
        <error capture code here...>
    }
}
```

On success and failures, everything works as expected...But during a test run, while trying to change the PrimarySMTPAddress to an invalid value, I get a WARNING (not error) that the new email address doesn't adhere to an e-mail address policy so it will not be changed. But since this is a warning, the `try`/`catch` doesn't trigger and the entire process wrongly finishes as successful.

I've tried:

1. adding `-WarningAction Stop` to the command and that does trigger the try/catch, but the error is too generic:

   > Command execution stopped because the preference variable "WarningPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop.
2. So I tried to capture the warning to a variable as well as file (to check for later when reporting success or failures), but all the ways I tried to capture failed, even though it continually displayed the warning to the screen.

   ```
   Set-Distributiongroup @Setparams -WarningVariable cmd_warn
   Set-Distributiongroup @Setparams 3> c:\temp\warnings.txt
   ...
   $command = "Set-Distributiongroup @Setparams"
   iex $command 3> c:\temp\warnings.txt
   ```

   But the file and variable are always empty, what am I doing wrong or missed?

Comment: does that cmdlet make a `-WarningVariable` parameter available?

Comment: *Why* are you defining a command in a string *then* using `iex`??

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 They were trying different approaches in order to capture the warning message, one of them being `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I guess I just don't follow the logic as to why anyone would ever resort to `iex` since there is a very specific use-case for it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 As AnsgarWiechers surmised, I was trying different approaches, I only tried iex because there was a post on the MS site where someone specified that's how they were able to finally capture output (but it didn't work for me).

Comment: @Namuna I'm not familiar with the exchange cmdlets so I'll bow out here, but I would try an all redirection if you're on PSv5+ (`*>logfile.txt`) as a hail mary.  What you've written should be working unless you're on a lower powershell version which may limit your options.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I tried just seeing if -WarningVariable would define it (it didn't) and also pre-defined it (cmd_warn = $null) and both had no luck.

Comment: @Namuna - arg! i am out of ideas ... i'm back to lurking for now. good luck!

Comment: the Set-Distributiongroup cmdlet is from Import-PSSession that connects to Exchange Server, if that makes a difference?

Comment: Similar to what @TheIncorrigible1 says, try redirecting other streams, e.g. `Set-Distributiongroup @Setparams 1>out1.txt 2>out2.txt 3>out3.txt 4>out4.txt 5>out5.txt` I have a funny feeling that it may be simply using `Write-Host` to write the message instead of the proper `Write-Warning`...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that you're using **`Import-PSSession`**, which creates an (in-memory) module with ***proxy functions* that transparently call commands of the same name on a remote machine**, a concept known as ***implicit remoting***.

Unfortunately, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0-preview.4, the implementation of **this feature has a number of problems** with respect to preference variables, common parameters, and output streams.

In your specific case, try the following **workaround**:

```
Invoke-Command { Set-Distributiongroup @Setparams } -WarningVariable cmd_warn
if ($cmd_warn) { ... } # warning was emitted
```

Note that the `Invoke-Command` call here doesn't itself perform remoting; it is merely a *local* invocation wrapper that makes the `-WarningVariable` common parameter work when applied to *it*.

Comment: That works. Are these issues you mention to be fixed in future versions of PS?

Comment: `@using:Setparams` **

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: There is no _immediate_ remote execution involved here (no `-ComputerName` used with `Invoke-Command`), so  `$using:` shouldn't be used.

Comment: @mklement0 missed that.  Would this example workaround the bug with implicit remote sessions then?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: According to my tests, yes; all `-*Variable` parameters seem to work if you apply them to the `Invoke-Command` wrapper; but with respect to stream management there are limitations that I've found no way to work around; I will update the answer later to state these limitations.

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld: I hope so, but I don't even know to what extent there is official awareness of the problem; I will file a bug at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues soonish.